# PhoneGap InAppBrowser access token sessions not connecting

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using PhoneGap 3.0.0 and trying to create a 'simple' login and connection with facebook in order to use Facebook's post dialog to post on behalf of my application to users' Facebook pages.

Here is my understanding of how the connection logic should work:
 1.  he application calls out facebook login in a new window (within the application itself), but it is linked to our app data
 2.  so, when FB gets a successful login, they redirect to OUR server, but now with a live Facebook accessToken
 3.  with it, in my server, I get the session data of the person
 4.  then automatically, that mini-browser within the application closes
 5.  and comes back to the application
 6.  now I make an alert of the facebook token
 7.  and then I require our server for the user's token from my application
 8.  once I retrieve our Token, I can initiate the automatic load of information into the application... that's it
 9. when the mini-browser closes and we get back to the application I retrieve our session token, automatically

**  The problem here is that this action is not happening, the session register is not happening in our server for some reason.  It does work in the test module that I developed, but not in the complete application even with the same module... that's the problem here.  I get perfectly the access token from facebook, but I don't get it from our server... like their session in our server never gets registered.

Comment: I have looked at forum upon forum upon forum both on here (Stackoverflow) and github with nothing...  Anyone have any SUCCESS with this connection??  I know its something very simple (hopefully) that I am missing.  Thanks!!  I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Is your fb app in sandbox mode?